# Valgrind 3.10.0 compilation failing for MIPS target with "opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2"

Tags: mips, valgrind, opcode

I am trying to cross compile valgrind 3.10.0 for mips32r2, but, I am getting the following error during compilation. Could anyone help with this issue, please?

I did the following configure step.

```
CC=/home/bin/mipsel-percello-linux-gnu-gcc; ./configure CFLAGS="-mips32r2" --host=mipsel-percello-linux-gnu

$TOOLCHAIN/Percello/MIPSel/bin/mipsel-percello-linux-gnu-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../include -I../VEX/pub -I../VEX/pub -DVGA_mips32=1 -DVGO_linux=1 -DVGP_mips32_linux=1 -DVGPV_mips32_linux_vanilla=1 -Ipriv  -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-zero-length -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin  -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-long-long -mips32r2 -fno-stack-protector -MT priv/libvex_mips32_linux_a-guest_mips_helpers.o -MD -MP -MF priv/.deps/libvex_mips32_linux_a-guest_mips_helpers.Tpo -c -o priv/libvex_mips32_linux_a-guest_mips_helpers.o `test -f 'priv/guest_mips_helpers.c' || echo './'`priv/guest_mips_helpers.c
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:3759: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.s.l $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:3782: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.l.d $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:3805: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.l.s $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:3828: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.d.l $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:3989: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `trunc.l.d $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4012: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `trunc.l.s $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4081: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `round.l.d $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4104: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `round.l.s $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4173: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `floor.l.d $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4196: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `floor.l.s $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4265: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `ceil.l.d $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4288: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `ceil.l.s $f24,$f24'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4604: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.s.l $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4626: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.l.d $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4647: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.l.s $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4669: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `cvt.d.l $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4819: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `trunc.l.d $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4840: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `trunc.l.s $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4905: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `round.l.d $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:4991: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `floor.l.d $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:5012: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `floor.l.s $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:5077: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `ceil.l.d $f20,$f20'
/tmp/cc3sKk0b.s:5098: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips32r2 (mips32r2) `ceil.l.s $f20,$f20'
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the opcodes it is complaining about are floating point operations. 
Looks like your target processor might not have a hardware floating point unit. Try adding the `-msoft-float` option to the gcc command line.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. I tried using -msoft-float, but, still faced the same issue. I found the following [link](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-01/msg00183.html). which talks about missing opcodes in binutils. But, if this is the case, then, I will have to get an update to my toolchain.

Comment: Your link dates from 2006. If your toolchain is older than that, it certainly needs updating! Have you tried the free Mentor/Codesourcery toolchain? http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/